# Enums and Arrays using Swift

Tags: swift, enums

I have declared an enum

```
enum MenuItem {
   case Item(String, Bool)
}
```

I have an array of this enums

```
let menuList = [
    MenuItem.Item("Title_1", true),
    MenuItem.Item("Title_2", false),
    MenuItem.Item("Title_3", true),

]
```

Now, from the above array how do I get the array of strings?

```
["Title_1", "Title_2", "Title_3"]
```

Comment: I'm not sure an enum is the best choice here, I think a struct with two variables would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to filter out `Item` cases from your array, and get out an array of the strings from their associated values, you could use `flatMap` and [pattern matching](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID424) to achieve this. For example:

```
// your array of enums
let menuList = [
    MenuItem.Item("Title_1", true),
    MenuItem.Item("Title_2", false),
    MenuItem.Item("Title_3", true),
]

let arrayOfStrings:[String] = menuList.flatMap {

    // if the element is of case .Item, return its string from the associated value
    if case .Item(let str, _) = $0 {return str}

    // else return nil (flatMap will filter out nil from the resultant array)
    return nil
}

print(arrayOfStrings) // ["Title_1", "Title_2", "Title_3"]
```

Although I have to question your use of an enum here. If it only has one case, a struct would be more appropriate (I'm unsure whether you simplified it for the sake of the question).